# Storing Multiple Values in View State

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm using a grid view control and I want to store a column's value (string) for multiple row selection. These values I want to store into a variable ( might be into a Array List or Data Table) as well as I want to save those value in View state.

Comment: Show us your code and where it fails

Comment: Actually I was asking for generalize approach.

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works. We are no search engine, to cover topics for you which have been discussed hundreds of times already. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask]